# D3.js and Angular 'this' element conflict

Tags: angular, d3.js

Using D3.js on my Angular 6 project I am selecting a element and adding some text on it. After this I want to call my typeScript function but the `this` is refering to D3.js element.

Here is a sample code:

```
MyVisulizationFuncn(){
d3.select("p").text("Thanks for your time to solve this").on("click", this.myFunciton());
}

myFunciton(){
console.log("I finally get called");
}
```

Can someone suggest how to call a function defined in my same component.ts file in d3 on click event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign `this` to a variable and call the function through variable.

```
MyVisulizationFuncn(){
  let th = this;
  d3.select("p").text("Thanks for your time to solve this").on("click", th.myFunciton());
}
```